# Gimp: Apply gradient only on colored parts (not on transparent spaces) of a layer/image

Tags: gimp

I have an image that I've put into a new layer. This image has a lot of transparent empty spaces. I have colorized the non-transparent spaces in black. The transparent parts are still transparent.

I would want to apply a gradient only on the black parts of the image/layer, leaving the transparent spaces... well... transparent.

How can I do that? Should I use masks and layers modes together?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved!

> Menu "Layer" > Transparency > Alpha to Selection THEN: Select > Invert

:-)

Comment: Locking the transparency of the layer in the layers dialog and then applying the gradient might be faster; it has the addtional benefit of keeping any selection you might have intact, and is also persistent.

Comment: Alpha to selection is actually a bad solution, since the edge pixels are likely half-transparent, and so half-selected, and so half-painted again. The alpha-lock mentioned above is the only good solution.